# looking for a windows tool that would allow me to select zones on the screen and duplicate them somewhere else as an overlay

Tags: windows, gaming

I'm looking for a windows tool that would allow me to take parts of the screen and display them somewhere else overlaid on top of a game window, to "relocate" or zoom in UI for example.

I haven't found anything of the sort on google, does this even exist?

note: it's not to show those things on stream, but the idea is kind of the same except for the local user.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean by somewhere else?

Comment: anywhere on the screen. take something like a health bar for instance, in a game where devs decided to put it at the bottom with a 5px10px size: I'd like to set the overlay to display this in the middle of the screen enlarged to 50x100 for instance.

of course it wouldn't move anything in the original UI, but having the possibility to have a duplicate in a more convenient location and maybe bigger is the kind of accessibility I'm looking for.

Comment: So it should be just on the same screen, where the game runs, or have I mised something?

Comment: yeah, just an overlay.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don´t know any software which can manage what you want, but if you need it for some single game some modification could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Today I stumbled upon [WindowTop](https://windowtop.info/) app.

It can set windows on top, it also has a PiP (Picture-in-Picture) mode, which works like overlay, available for any windows, together with cropping a specific area. Read more about the feature itself [here](https://github.com/WindowTop/WindowTop-App/issues/133).

Unfortunately, the PiP feature requires premium version.